# Result of binary segmentation is blurred images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am working on a binary segmentation problem for which I have to segment the nuclei from the cells. I am using binary cross entropy as loss function with U-Net CNN model. The resultant images got some blurry effects. The more number of epochs I run the experiment, the more blurriness occurs. What leads to result such blurry effect and what change should I make to my model to get rid of that?

I have attached one sample resultant image produced after 4 epochs.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just threshold the result at some threshold value (I used 0.5 for convenience). However, you can use dice loss as in https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04117 (keras implementation can be found here: https://github.com/raghakot/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation), which tends to produce binary outputs. If the final result is better than using thresholding on the binary crossentropy output depends on your dataset though.

Comment: Thomas Pinetz : Yes, sure. I'll try everything which you suggested. But, is it common that binary cross entropy produces such blurry effects or is it happening just in my case?

Comment: That is common.